# Icon sticks to the default when combining 64-bit only

Tags: .net, wpf, msbuild

As I was preparing a new version of my program, I noticed that the binary has the stock icon when it compiles the code, when it should have changed the icon. I know that I have set a custom icon in the Properties menu, yet it's ignored by Visual Studio. Compiling it x86 or AnyCPU works fine. I implemented a fix for the ALINK error (since I am using .resx files for translations), still ignored. Switch to a different version of the .NET Framework, still nothing. Moved the icon to the Resources file, nothing. I am rather stumped by this. The only thing I know that happens is that a NuGet package I use does make a native image of the binaries.

Comment: Could you show the steps you used to define the new icon in `Properties` menu? And as a sanity check, are you sure the x64 binary you are checking is newly compiled, I ask this cos you may have checked the wrong output.

Comment: Are you sure you set the custom icon in the properties for all configurations, not just for x86/AnyCpu?